# If $a \mid c$ and $b \mid c$ where $a, b, c \in \mathbb{N}$, under what conditions does it follow that $a \mid b$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility, relations, equivalence-relations

The following question is pretty basic, and the underlying idea was used in the **"proof"** of a statement in this [hyperlinked answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3140086/28816) to another MSE question.

The question is as follows:

> If $a \mid c$ and $b \mid c$ where $a, b, c \in \mathbb{N}$, under what conditions does it follow that $a \mid b$?

**MY ATTEMPT**

Take $c = 20$.  $c$ factors as follows:
$$c = 20 = 4 \cdot 5 = 2 \cdot 10.$$

Note that we can take $a = 2$, $b = 10$.  And also note the counterexample $$a = 4 \nmid 5 = b.$$

So I think a condition under which
$$\bigg(a \mid c \text{ and } b \mid c\bigg) \implies a \mid b$$
is when
$$\frac{b}{a} \mid c.$$
But that condition is too *artificial* for my purposes.  Are there other more *natural* conditions?

Comment: What does $\frac ba$ mean if we don't know that $a\,|\,b$?  If it is just meant to be rational, then what does it mean to say that it divides $c$?

Comment: @lulu, if we know *a priori* that $\frac{b}{a} \mid c$, then it follows that $\frac{b}{a}$ is an integer.  (It forces $a \mid b$.)

Comment: @lulu, you are merely playing with words.  From the context, I meant divisibility in $\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: So...your test is that if $a$ divides $b$ then $a$ divides $b$?  It's obvious that $b\,|\,c$ implies that every factor of $b$ divides $c$.

Comment: @lulu, please reconsider the example given in the question.

Comment: Yes...you gave one example in which $a$ divided $b$.  So what?

Comment: @lulu: What is *your* point?

Comment: My point is that your "test" is circular at best.

Comment: @lulu: Indeed.  Which is why I consider it *artificial*.

Comment: To the serial downvoter:  I doubt if your high reputation could compensate for your lack of empathy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$c=1$ is the only possibility.

Indeed, if $c\neq 1$, then $c \text{ } | \text{ }c$ and $1 \text{ } | \text{ } c$, but obviously you don't have $c \text{ }  | \text{ } 1$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, @TheSilverDoe.  What about the example I have given?  $c = 20 = 2 \cdot 10$, so we can take $a = 2 \mid 10 = b$, but $1 \neq 20 = c$.

Comment: You give an example where $a \text{ }| \text{ } c$, $b \text{ }| \text{ } c$ and $a \text{ }| \text{ } b$. That does not mean that the implication $(a \text{ }| \text{ } c \text{ and } b \text{ }| \text{ } c) \Rightarrow a \text{ }| \text{ } b$ is true.

Comment: Ahh yes!  Valid arguments are not always sound!  Thank you.  Gladly accepting your answer now.